# link form-region attribute to Outlook

Tags: c#, plugins, outlook, office-interop

I created a form-region with some controls such as lables and textboxes.
I would like to fill the textboxes with current selected contact details.

When creating the form-region, I've added `theFormRegionMessageClassAttribute.Contact` to the form.
How can I access the contact details?
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a great work-through guide : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157865.aspx